# How can I fix the Incompatible shape: [32,32 vs. [32, 32, 912] Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am working with a custom loss in a model and I get this error

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Incompatible shapes: [32,32] vs. [32,32,912]
 [[{{node LogicalAnd}}]]
```

This is odd but I know it is a problem with the input_b which has a shape of (331, 912). So I looked at my model's shape and the input_b is not there. 
***EDIT***
So if fixed the issue with the second input not showing up. But I still get the same error. So my thought of it is because the second input was gone was wrong.

```html
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
input_a (InputLayer)            (None, 224, 224, 3)  0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
input_b (InputLayer)            (None, 912)          0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
model_1 (Model)                 (None, 2048)         20861480    input_a[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate_1 (Concatenate)     (None, 2960)         0           input_b[0][0]                    
                                                             model_1[1][0]                    
==================================================================================================
Total params: 20,861,480
Trainable params: 20,806,952
Non-trainable params: 54,528
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
None
```

So I don't know what is happening with this error. Then I would think it is due to the input layer not being there, but is it? Here is my model code

```
# Define new model
input_a = Input(shape=(224, 224, 3), name='input_a')
input_b = Input(shape=(912,), name='input_b')

embeddings = base_network(input_a) # loaded from a fine tuned model
final_data = Concatenate(axis=1)([input_b, embeddings])

batch_loss = batch_hard_triplet_loss(embeddings, input_b, 0.4, False)
model = Model(inputs=[input_a, input_b], outputs=final_data)
# Compile model
model.compile(loss=batch_loss, optimizer='adam')
```

Full error Logs

```
Preocessing data...
Shape of X train
(331, 224, 224, 3)
Shape of Y train
(331, 912)
(164, 224, 224, 3)
(164, 912)
Finished processing data.
Initializing Model...
WARNING:tensorflow:From     C:/Users/matthew.millar/Documents/reid/ReIDFullProject/AdvancedTensorflowTripleLoss.py:47: to_float (from tensorflow.python.ops.math_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use tf.cast instead.
Model Created.

Started Training model...
WARNING:tensorflow:From C:\Users\matthew.millar\Anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\math_grad.py:102: div (from     tensorflow.python.ops.math_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Deprecated in favor of operator or tf.math.divide.
Train on 332 samples, validate on 164 samples
Epoch 1/10
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File     "C:/Users/matthew.millar/Documents/reid/ReIDFullProject/AdvancedTensorflowTripleLoss.py", line 288, in <module>
callbacks=callbacks_list)
  File "C:\Users\matthew.millar\Anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1039, in fit
validation_steps=validation_steps)
  File "C:\Users\matthew.millar\Anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training_arrays.py", line 199, in fit_loop
outs = f(ins_batch)
  File "C:\Users\matthew.millar\Anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py", line 2715, in __call__
return self._call(inputs)
  File "C:\Users\matthew.millar\Anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py", line 2675, in _call
fetched = self._callable_fn(*array_vals)
  File "C:\Users\matthew.millar\Anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1439, in __call__
run_metadata_ptr)
  File "C:\Users\matthew.millar\Anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\errors_impl.py", line 528, in __exit__
c_api.TF_GetCode(self.status.status))
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Incompatible shapes: [32,32] vs. [32,32,912]
 [[{{node LogicalAnd}}]]
```

Here is the fit function so you know how I am sending the data in

```
history = model.fit(x=[x_train, y_train], y=dummy_y_train,
                epochs=EPOCH,
                batch_size=BATCHSIZE,
                shuffle=True,
                validation_data=([x_test, y_test], dummy_y_test),
                verbose=1,
                callbacks=callbacks_list)
```

Comment: Im commenting in case you don't get an answer, I will check this tomorrow.

Comment: would you give the full log of the error, it seems base_network might have different input_size different from input_images

Comment: X train is input_a Ytrain is input_b

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All right I figured it out after a good night's rest. 
There were several issues that were wrong with the code.

The first is I did a to_categorical to the second input as it was a string. This was an issue as I feel that keras saw it naturally as the label and messed up the input shape so it was [32,32,913] which is the batch size x the number of input data. So to fix this I change that input into an int which is what keras can read.

The second change was to change the input shape to a 1 which would be logical for the ints now.

so this is the final model and its working fine now

```
# Define new model
input_a = Input(shape=(224, 224, 3), name='input_a')
input_b = Input(shape=(1,), name='input_b')
embeddings = base_network(input_a) # loaded from a fine tuned model
batch_loss = batch_hard_triplet_loss(embeddings, input_b, 0.4, False)
model = Model(inputs=[input_a, input_b], outputs=embeddings)
```

I hope this helps out anyone who has this trouble in the future.